# How to test if my Oracle DB version supports the PIVOT function?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I need to work out a way to determine if Oracle is 11g or newer, because essentially I need to know if the DB I'm running on supports PIVOT.

Getting the version number ifself is not that difficult, so I've got:

```
select * from v$version
```

Unfortunately, this does not give a simple number, but 5 records including stings and various different version numbers:

```
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bi
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.5.0 - Production
CORE    10.2.0.5.0  Production
TNS for Linux: Version 10.2.0.5.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.5.0 - Production
```

So, is there a way to determine if my Oracle is 11g or higher, or even better, if the DB supports the PIVOT statement?

Thanks!

Comment: Although the selected answer is really elegant, I probably would have done it the ugly way by using some of the built-in Regex functions, some casting to INT and then a comparison.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As one of the methods of determining whether your Oracle version supports `PIVOT` or not is to query the [V$RESERVED_WORDS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/dynviews_2134.htm#i1412941) view to find out if the reserved word `PIVOT` is there or not.

```
SQL> select keyword
  2    from v$reserved_words
  3   where keyword = 'PIVOT'
  4  ;

KEYWORD
---------
PIVOT
```

---

If you are writing a code (as you've mentioned in the comment to the @Ben's answer, quote `I'm creating a procedure that generates and executes SQL statements for a datamart`) that is going to take advantage of version specific features you could (and it's preferred approach) use [dbms_db_version](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_dbver.htm) package for conditional compilation. For instance:

```
 create or replace some_proc
 is
 begin
   $if dbms_db_version.ver_le_10_2 -- for example
   $then
     -- features up to 10g r2 version 
   $else
     -- current release  
   $end
 end;
```

Comment: I'd be careful using `v$reserved_words` for this.  New features sometimes start as undocumented features.  There is a chance that PIVOT was a reserved word before it was really available.  You should check for this in 10.2.0.5 first (I don't have an instance of that version available to test.)

Answer (score 2):

I hope followings will help you

[Check Oracle Version](http://www.mydigitallife.info/check-oracle-version/)

[Identifying Your Oracle Database Software Release](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/dba004.htm)

Comment: Nice links!  It is customary on Stackoverflow to just display the answer and maybe a link to the answer should the OP want to follow it.  Your "answer" isn't wrong, but you could have made it a better answer.  Please see [Ben's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14057301/630284) as an example.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little confused about why you wouldn't know what version of Oracle you're using already.

However, you can use the system view [PRODUCT_COMPONENT_VERSION](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_5148.htm#REFRN29037) to get the current version. It's what Oracle recommends to [check your current release number](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/dba004.htm#ADMIN11039).

```
select * from PRODUCT_COMPONENT_VERSION
```

So you can see the output; it works in [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/5573) as well.

Comment: Well I need to determine that, because I'm creating a procedure that generates and executes SQL statements for a datamart. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I believe Ben's answer best answers the question in the title ("What version of Oracle DB...").  However, the REAL question that the OP is asking is "How to test if my Oracle DB version supports the PIVOT function?"